# MPTCP configuration in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXRbp.png <-a picture which captured for understanding what i said

I want to ask about installation & implementation of MPTCP in ubuntu.

By following an web site, multipath-tcp.org, i'm going to set MPTCP test environments.

After finishing configuring apt-repository, i typed command 'netstat -m'.
but, i did'nt see MPTCP connection.

As i guess the reason of this problem, the component have to be in red box to apply it to net.mptcp.mptcp_path_manager. 
because of absence of 'fullmesh' in red box, we can see event like green box. 
in case of blue box, we can see that 'default' can be applied to net.mptcp.mptcp_path_manager. correctly.

i want to know that how can i add additional component to red box?? 
if you know that, please ask to me..!

- I have pool English skill, sorry and thank to your effort to read my question.

Answer (score 0):

In your image it seems to be a bug. I suggest you to install a previous version. Be sure that you are using the correct MPTCP and Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 0):

After a successful installation of the MPTCP kernel, you need to manually switch to that kernel in the GRUB options once you reboot.